# CodeIgniter: CSS cannot display images as background

Tags: css, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter 2. I'm trying to display some images using the background url in CSS.

I have placed the images and css folders in my `index.php` directory level and I can access the images and CSS folders from my browser as well, so I don't think its an `.htaccess` problem.

My code for my CSS file is as follows:

```
.multiplebgs .upload-creative-browse-button:hover {
  background:
    url(/images/progress_meter_leftcap_round.png) 0 -200px no-repeat,
    url(/images/progress_meter_rightcap_round.png) 100% -200px no-repeat,
    url(/images/progress_meter_fill.png) 0 -200px repeat-x;
  color: #98BD5E;
}
```

For some reason, its not displaying the images even though the rest of the CSS styling loads fine.

Comment: which browser are you testing this on? they don't all support multiple background images

Comment: I'm guessing you have a similar declaration for the non-hover without the -200px, does that one work, and are you sure you're shifting it the right direction with the -200px? maybe it's meant to be 200px on your image sprite

Comment: actually i worked on it previously without using a php framework (hardcoded the darn thing). But i needed to port it over to codeigniter for uniformity. The code works fine. My problem is that when i use it with code igniter, the css doesnt seem to be able to get the picture..

Comment: oh and i tested it on chrome 14, ff7, safari.... all of which, the original code (the one without a framework) worked fine and the one with code igniter doesnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you said this:

> I have placed the images and css *folders*...

I assume your folder structure is like this:

```
root
|--/css    (root/css)
|--/images (root/images)
```

So you have to specify image paths this way:

```
url(../images/img.png)
```

Here's the full code:

```
.multiplebgs .upload-creative-browse-button:hover {
  background:
    url(../images/progress_meter_leftcap_round.png) 0 -200px no-repeat,
    url(../images/progress_meter_rightcap_round.png) 100% -200px no-repeat,
    url(../images/progress_meter_fill.png) 0 -200px repeat-x;
  color: #98BD5E;
}
```